Calculating generator over-speed following sudden disconnection and delayed valve closure
I'm working on an exam question related to power systems and need help calculating the over-speed of a generator following a sudden disconnection from the grid. The question is:

A 475 MVA, 2 pole, turbo-alternator delivers 350 MW to a 50 Hz system operating at 49.97 Hz. If the generator circuit breaker is suddenly opened and the main steam valves take 375 ms to operate, calculate, to 4 significant digits, the over-speed of the generator.   The stored energy of the machine (generator and turbine) at synchronous speed is 4.5 kWs/kVA.

I started by calculating the total stored kinetic energy in the generator using the formula:
Total Stored Energy = MVA Rating × Stored Energy per kVA
= 475,000 kVA × 4.5 kWs/kVA
= 2,137,500 kWs
I'm stuck on how to translate this stored energy into an over-speed value in Hz, considering the generator's momentary disconnection from the load. I'm aware that the kinetic energy will cause the generator to speed up until the steam valves close, but I'm unsure how to calculate this effect accurately.
Specific questions:
How do I calculate the generator's over-speed in Hz using the stored kinetic energy and the time until the steam valves close?
Is there a specific formula or method that applies to this scenario, considering the generator's characteristics and the initial operating conditions?
